# OpenGL/glut/stdc++ build errors

Tags: c++, opengl, linker-errors, glut

I'm using Ubuntu and tried using synaptic to install everything that had the word "GLUT" in it and also SDL and opengl . But still a simple program fails to compile . It shows this :

```
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0xe): undefined reference to `glClear'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x1a): undefined reference to `glBegin'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x2e): undefined reference to `glVertex2i'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x33): undefined reference to `glEnd'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `glFlush'
/tmp/ccnwQeLu.o: In function `MyInit()':
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x4c): undefined reference to `glGetString'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x57): undefined reference to `std::cout'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x5c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream >& std::operator >(std::basic_ostream >&, unsigned char const*)'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x6c): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream >& std::operator >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x78): undefined reference to `glGetString'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x83): undefined reference to `std::cout'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x88): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream >& std::operator >(std::basic_ostream >&, unsigned char const*)'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x98): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream >& std::operator >(std::basic_ostream >&, char const*)'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0xc0): undefined reference to `glClearColor'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0xdf): undefined reference to `glColor3f'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0xec): undefined reference to `glPointSize'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0xf8): undefined reference to `glMatrixMode'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `glLoadIdentity'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `gluOrtho2D'
/tmp/ccnwQeLu.o: In function `main':
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `glutInit'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
/tmp/ccnwQeLu.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x1cb): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x1d0): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'
/tmp/ccnwQeLu.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If I use g++ instead of gcc I get this:

```
vim opebgl1.cpp
g++ opengl1.cpp -o opengl1 -lGL -lstdc++ -lc -lm
 and then get this :
/tmp/ccCJBuIl.o: In function `MyInit()':
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `gluOrtho2D'
/tmp/ccCJBuIl.o: In function `main':
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `glutInit'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowSize'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x18d): undefined reference to `glutCreateWindow'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So  what  do I really need to start working with opengl in Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you linking in all the appropriate libraries when building your application?

Comment: I included these header files :#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

Comment: Also, are you building with `g++` or `gcc`?

Comment: Including header files is only half of what you need to do. That allows the program to compile but not link. The command that ultimately creates your application (or library) should link to the libraries you used otherwise it won't know where to get all these symbols from. Post your build commands and we can give you some pointers.

Comment: Use `g++` to build C++ source. You'll find the errors relating to things like `std::cout` go away then. `g++` is really just a wrapper around `gcc` that automatically links to the standard C++ libraries for you. If you use `gcc` you have to do it manually. It's far easier to use `g++`.

Comment: @user553492: I hope you don't mind me editing your question. Someone has marked it for closure as being off-topic, presumably because you phrased it as an Ubuntu installation question. Of course it turned out to be a programming question so I've just made that a bit clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add "-lstdc++ -lGL" to your linker flags.
Or try to compile it like this:

```
g++ opengl1.cpp -o opengl1 -lGL -lGLU -lc -lm
```

(edit: added -lGLU, removed -lstdc++)

Comment: Now i`m getting 
/tmp/ccCJBuIl.o: In function `MyInit()':
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x12d): undefined reference to `gluOrtho2D'
/tmp/ccCJBuIl.o: In function `main':
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x14a): undefined reference to `glutInit'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x156): undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x16d): undefined reference to 
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x181): undefined reference to `glutInitWindowPosition'

opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x19e): undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'
opengl1.cpp:(.text+0x1a3): undefined reference to `glutMainLoop'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: @user:  Also add -lglut and -lGLU to the left of -lGL.

Comment: Why would you need `-lstdc++` if you are using `g++`? It appears the problem is that @user553492 is using `gcc` by mistake.

Comment: @pelya:  -lstdc++ is implicit when you compile/link with g++ (unless you explicitly disable it)

Comment: The errors seem to have gon with using g++ . The only problem now is that the program compiles but when I run it , it says command not found .

Comment: @user:  You probably don't have "." (the current directory) in your path.  Just run it like this:  `./opengl1`.

Answer (score 3):

You should link it with glut and GLU as well:

```
g++ opengl1.cpp -o opengl1 -lGL -lstdc++ -lc -lm -lglut -lGLU
```

Files ended with **.cpp** must be compiled with **g++**. The rest of the errors are related to the linking process, and they should not happen if you build your application with the command I suggested above. If they do, make sure you have installed *libglut* and *libglu*.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you are using `g++` to build your C++ files to avoid the linker errors pertaining to the C++ standard library.

To resolve the GLUT symbols you probably just need to add `-lglut` to your final build command.

Answer (score 1):

While compiling the code you must mention some parameters according to your includes.
You already used `-lGL`, `-lm` etc.
To use `gluOrtho2D` the parameter to be used is `-lGLU`
and for other functions that begin with `glut` use `-lglut`