# Compile error when linking against two libraries in C++

Tags: c++

compile command:

```
 g++  ast01.cpp -o ast01 -lglu -lglut
```

error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lglu
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function displaySpiral(): error: undefined reference to 'glClear'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function displaySpiral(): error: undefined reference to 'glBegin'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function displaySpiral(): error: undefined reference to 'glColor3ub'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function displaySpiral(): error: undefined reference to 'glEnd'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function displaySpiral(): error: undefined reference to 'glFlush'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function openGLinit(int, char**): error: undefined reference to 'glClearColor'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function openGLinit(int, char**): error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function openGLinit(int, char**): error: undefined reference to 'glLoadIdentity'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function openGLinit(int, char**): error: undefined reference to 'gluOrtho2D'
/tmp/ccjQZPPr.o:ast01.cpp:function openGLinit(int, char**): error: undefined reference to 'glMatrixMode'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: I think the key is right here: `/usr/bin/ld: error: cannot find -lglu`. Do you have GLU installed?

Comment: You might want to look at this question (which came up under "Related" over to the right): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5410832/opengl-glut-stdc-build-errors?rq=1  I think you'll need "-lGLU" (note the capitals) and "-lGL".

Comment: Can you post ``ast01.cpp`` source code?

Comment: I'm having trouble posting the source code. Something about it being properly formatted.

Comment: g++ -lglut -lGLU -lGL -o ast01.cpp
i used this and it worked! Case sensitive. Thanks